# Adding Basemaps in Map Control using ArcGIS Engine

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine, basemap

I am developing a .Net application that is using ArcGIS Engine 10.8. I would like to add programmatically the "Add Basemap" functionality into the application's Map Control.

How can I add this command to my application?

Command: ESRI_BaseMap_BasemapCommand
GUID: {76B26001-63CF-4CAC-A7E0-91CEE8686FAC}
BaseMap.BaseMapCommand

[image: pic 1]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [inheriting from a command](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#CommandInheritingBaseCommand.htm). Not so sure how it works in ArcEngine but I suspect its similar?